# Drawing the shortest path from point a to point b given an array of coordinates to use

Tags: java, graphics2d

I am currently making a map generator using Java. I am using arrays to store coordinates, which are then used to draw land. So I also have cities, and I want to draw the most direct path from city a to city b without crossing the water, AKA, only using the coordinates that are stored as land. How can I do this? I have tried many algorithms a;ready, like solving systems to make sure things do not overlap (which takes too long, as i have 75,000 points) and also finding the nearest city that does not have any water in between the two, found by drawing a best fit line and solving just one systems (extremely inaccurate and probably just wrong). Thanks for all the help in advance!

Comment: Do you think it's a form of the NP-hard traveling salesman problem?  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Travelling_salesman_problem

Comment: @danh Clever, however I don't understand I would avoid hitting any "water" coordinates.

Comment: You'd need to rule out arcs between city pairs that cross water.  Those could be computed in advance.  Then it's a matter of applying one of the proposed algorithms with an extra requirement to reject partial solutions containing water-crossing arcs.

Comment: @danh Interesting. So I would pre-generate paths for each city to city road, and then keep the ones that do not intersect with the water? How do I check if it does? I was thinking solving systems of equations to check for intersections (its not too bad because it will just stop solving if one point intersects). Is there a better way to do it?

Comment: @danh i just posted an answer to this q, I dont know if you got a notification. Thanks!

Comment: Look into pathfinding algorithms like A* or Djikstra's. Consider giving water an infinite cost in these implementations.